# Microsoft azure time trigger function

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions

I am using time trigger function to schedule my function to run and perform some calculation daily. And i am using this approach to trigger the function is as below

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 0 20 * * 1-5"
    }
  ]
}
```

But the issue i am facing is my scheduler time trigger function won't trigger at all. And this is in the production.

Comment: Your time trigger is scheduled to be running  Mo-Fr at 20:00:00. Is is correct?
https://arminreiter.com/2017/02/azure-functions-time-trigger-cron-cheat-sheet/

Comment: @AndriyBilous Yes the time trigger is schedule from Mon-Fri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CRON expression is no problem, it should work with no problem. Please make sure you have success deploy the function app.

On local, start azure function with `func host start --verbose` can get the next excute time of the time trigger：

[image]

And on azure, please go to the application insight, and run `traces`, you will get:

[image]

(Your time trigger only run once daily, and the default time zone is utc standard time. So maybe just you didn't check at the right time?)

By the way, please make sure your code is no error or exception.